Launching app from notification with extras
When application started from notification while application is not running or in background, extras is not available.
However application is running or in background, I can reach to extras. SplashActivity is the main activity. How can I reach them when application started from scratch?
PushNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService:
val intent = Intent(this, SplashActivity::class.java).apply {
    flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    putExtra("TEST", 16)
}
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Random.nextInt(), intent, FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

AndroidManifest:
<application
    android:name=".HiltApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_logo_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.X">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.X.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".service.PushNotificationService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/notification_channel_general" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/app_logo" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/blue" />
</application>

SplashActivity:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SplashActivity : ComponentActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        Splash()
    }

    Log.d("SPLASH", "onCreate: intent action ${intent.action}")
    Log.d("SPLASH", "onCreate: intent test extra ${intent.getIntExtra("TEST", -1)}")
}

}

Logs:

onCreate: intent action android.intent.action.MAIN
onCreate: intent test extra -1 // in extras it is 16

Notification Payload:
const message = {
    token: "TOKEN",
    notification: {
        title: d.title,
        body: d.content
    },
    android: {
        notification: {
            channel_id: "fcm_channel",
        },
    },
    data: {
        title: d.title,
        content: d.content,
    },
};


When the app is in the background, the notification is received in the system tray. So if you want to test if your data is reaching your SplashActivity correctly, you will need to test it with a payload.
For example:
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Tittle",
      "body":"Body"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Test" : "value",
    }
  }
}

More information here.

I added the payload. As far as I understand, payload should contain only data block. Mine has both of them. If it has notification block (even android/notification block exists for channel), it is handling by FCM SDK.

Have you launched this notification from postman?

I have launched in NodeJS application with Firebase Admin SDK.
